# Add a new column with random 11 digit number

Tags: r

I'm trying to add a couple of random numbers to my data.  I want the number to be 11 digits long.

I've tried

```
data$new_column <- paste(sample(0:9,11,replace = T), collapse = "")
```

which creates the same 11 digit number, but I'm looking for different numbers in each cell (preferably non-repeating, though it's not a deal breaker).

I've also tried

```
data$new_column <- sample(10000000000, size = nrow(data), replace = T)
```

which creates a different random number in each row, but not all 11 digits in length.

Has anyone suggest a way I can do this in base r without using a loop?

Comment: If you sample with a minimum number of 1e10, up to maximum of 1e11 - 1, you should have 11 digit numbers to use, something like: `sample(1e10:(1e11-1), size = ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking along the same lines you were, with just a slight modification:

```
data$new_column <- sample(10000000000:99999999999, nrow(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
data$new_column <- as.character(trunc(runif(nrow(data), 1e10, 1e11 - 1)))
```

**Edit**: that was assuming you needed 11-digits that don't start with `0`. If that's okay, then you can simplify with

```r
data$new_column <- sprintf("%011.0f", sample(1e11-1, nrow(data)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate 11 random number and paste them together to form 11-digit numbers. Use `replicate` to repeat this process `n` times. Some numbers would start with 0 in which case you can add 0's to the right using `str_pad`.

```
n <- nrow(data)
len <- 11

temp <- replicate(n, as.numeric(paste0(sample(0:9, len, replace = TRUE), collapse = '')))
data$new_column <- as.numeric(stringr::str_pad(temp, len, 'right', pad = '0'))
```